# Thread 1: Breakpoint 4.1 - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Whenever I call my buildDateString method using "println(buildDateString("xx","xx","xx","xx","xx")" my app crashes, giving me the error "Thread 1: breakpoint 4.1"

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

func getDateFromString(dateString: String) -> NSDate? {
    var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy-kk-mm-ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
}

func getCurrentDateAsArray() -> [Int] {
    var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy-kk-mm-ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

    var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    return stringToIntArray(dateString.componentsSeparatedByString("-"))
}

func stringToIntArray(stringArray: [String]) -> [Int] {
    var intArray: [Int] = []

    for element in stringArray {
        intArray.append(element.toInt()!)
    }

    return intArray
}

func intToStringArray(intArray: [Int]) -> [String] {
    var stringArray: [String] = []

    for element in intArray {
        stringArray.append("\(element)")
    }

    return stringArray
}

func buildDateString(day: String, month: String, hour: String, minute: String, second: String) -> String {
    var dayValue = day
    var monthValue = month
    var hourValue = hour
    var minuteValue = minute
    var secondValue = second
    var currentDate = getCurrentDateAsArray()

    println(currentDate)

    dayValue = dayValue.utf16Count == 1 ? "0" + dayValue : dayValue
    monthValue = monthValue.utf16Count == 1 ? "0" + monthValue : monthValue
    hourValue = hourValue.utf16Count == 1 ? "0" + hourValue : hourValue
    minuteValue = minuteValue.utf16Count == 1 ? "0" + minuteValue : minuteValue
    secondValue = secondValue.utf16Count == 1 ? "0" + secondValue : secondValue

    var bool1 = monthValue.toInt() > currentDate[0]
    var bool2 = monthValue.toInt() == currentDate[0] && dayValue.toInt() > currentDate[1]
    var bool3 = monthValue.toInt() == currentDate[0] && dayValue.toInt() == currentDate[1] && hourValue.toInt() > currentDate[3]
    var bool4 = monthValue.toInt() == currentDate[0] && dayValue.toInt() == currentDate[1] && hourValue.toInt() == currentDate[3] && minuteValue.toInt() > currentDate[4]
    var bool5 = monthValue.toInt() == currentDate[0] && dayValue.toInt() == currentDate[1] && hourValue.toInt() == currentDate[3] && minuteValue.toInt() == currentDate[4] && secondValue.toInt() > currentDate[5]

    if (bool1 || bool2 || bool3 || bool4 || bool5) {
        currentDate[2] = currentDate[2] + 1
    }

    var currentDateStringArray: [String] = [monthValue, dayValue, "\(currentDate[2])", hourValue,minuteValue, secondValue]

    return "-".join(currentDateStringArray)
}
```

I don't understand why this happens, and xCode doesn't give me any hints to what the error might be.

I am using the iOS 8.2 SDK with xCode 6.2 beta 4

The error is thrown to this line:

```
println(buildDateString("12", "5", "12", "12", "7"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have breakpoint set up, I believe it's on the line:

```
println(buildDateString("xx","xx","xx","xx","xx")
```

Just remove/disable the breakpoint and it should be fine.

To deactivate breakpoints you can select from xCode menu Debug and Deactivate breakpoints, or use apple key + Y shortcut.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.
One question, why is this breakpoint set up? I don't recall setting it

Comment: You set it probably inadvertently. It will bw worth yout time to read the Xcode documentation. Breakpoints are very usefull for debugging.

Comment: I believe you set it up by accident. To set it up yo just need to click on the desired line ( on the left hand side), it's very common 'mistake' to do, but it's very easily to remove it, just grab the breakpoint icon and drag it away.

Comment: I should probably read the xCode documentation, thank you